# Policy loss in DDPG

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement DDPG algorithm.

However I have a query that why actor loss is calculated as negative mean of the model predicted Q values in the states we are in.

Shouldn't it be like the difference of the Q values when random action is taken and Q values of the model predicted actions in that state.

Basically if a random action is generating a better Q value...only then the actor Q value should be updated else we already have the value and no need to propagate actor loss separately..it will be taken care in value loss.

I know this post ought to be in AI forum but stackoverflow seems to provide good and quick responses that is why posting here